# Passing objects between react native tab navigator's screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I have a bottom tab-bar navigator and has 3 screens. In Menu screen, I am trying to pick a menu-item and in Cart-screen, which is 2nd route of tab navigator, show the selected menu item.
Here is my tab-navigator

```
const MenuNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Menu:MenuScreen,
    Cart:CartScreen,
    Options:OptionScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Menu') {
          iconName = `ios-md-book${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Cart') {
          iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }else if(routeName ==='Options'){
          iconName=`ios-options${focused? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
        // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={horizontal ? 20 : 25} color={tintColor} />;
    },
    }),tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }

  );
```

I have a menu-item object in a button's onPress function like this:

```
var menuitem={itemId:item.itemId,
                    name:item.name,
                    ingredients:item.ingredients,
                    price:item.price,
                    type:item.type};
```

and assigning it in the same onPress funttion to the MenuScreen's menuItem object.

```
this.setState({menuItem:Object.assign({},menuitem)});
```

And successfully rendering it in a modal which belongs to Menu-screen,but I want to render it in Cart-screen too.

But then how will I reach that object from the Cart Screen? 
the project has so many codes and screens so I only copied related parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Redux to provide an overarching store across all Screens that you use to share data. If you are navigating across screens, you can also pass data by using

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("NewScreen", {data: dataToBePassed})
```

You can then retrieve the data by using

```
this.props.navigation.getParam("data", defaultValue)
```

You can learn more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html).

Comment: Yeah i forgot the mention that, i read react-navigation and react-native official tutorials, none of them worked. İ dont want to use redux because i got 2 day for this task i dont have enough time to learn. İ tried to use this.props.navigation.setParams and getParam , it caused the params become "unidentified" in CartScreen. İn bottomTabBarNavigation ,i dont use navigate function it handles itself obviously, so where does it calling navigate() to change routes ? Then i can modify its default behaviour like your example ?

Comment: Have you tried using setParams to modify the params in that route's state, and then accessing the data from there? You can reference under "state" here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Comment: yes i am trying it,here is what i did: MenuScreen>TouchableOpacity>onPress: this.props.navigation.setParams({mycart:this.state.menuItem});  then i try to get the parameter from CartScreen with this : this.props.navigation.getParam('mycart'); and then i log this to console , it give me unidentified object. Am i doing it wrong ? What's the correct way ?

Comment: Never mind, setting params only allow for the state to access the current params for the current screen. I think the only elegant solution is to use Redux. There's hack that I can think of where you create a variable in a separate js file and import it to both screens, then change that variable to share the data, but I don't know how well that would work.

Comment: Thanks for your interest mate, i solved it with this function,i found out the correct way is like this :  onPress={() => {
              this.setModal(false);
              this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.setParams({
                params: { mycart: this.state.menuItem },
                   key: "Cart",
                    }));  then i pull that object from other screen with getParam.I guess this an help to other beginners like me maybe.